# Getting 404error when trying to display a jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, controller

I am trying to get the value of a form from a jsp to use in a function in the controller and display another jsp

```
<form action="/uc">
   <input name="cnp" type="text">
      <br>
      <br>
   <input type="submit" value="Find">
</form>
```

This one is my Controller method

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/uc", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String userContracts(@RequestParam("cnp") String cnp, Model model)
    {
        List<Contract> ContractList = new ArrayList<Contract>();

        ContractList = cl.getContractsOfUser(cnp);

        model.addAttribute("ContractList", ContractList);
        System.out.println("In uc");
        return "UserContracts";
    }
```

Comment: can you confirm that context is added to uri in action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks pedram ezzati for the help!

The problem was that I had to use

```
<form action="http://localhost:8080/SpringWebTemplate/uc.html">
```

My previous attempts where either without the .html or just using /uc

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your package is scan while spring come up.

In app-config.xml file check below tag

context:component-scan base-package="com.test.ashok"

Comment: Nope, that wasn't it